# Appending an xsl "variable" to an xsl:if test

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this, as I'm still fairly new with XSL.  I currently have an `<xsl:for-each>` that I am looping through, and I need to append part of the for each on to a test value.  I hope I explained this well enough.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="withdraw_source"
          data-target="dpx-container_{./account_number}"
          value="dpx_{./account_number}">
      <xsl:if test="//form_data/withdraw_source = 'dpx'">
          <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
   </input>
   <strong>
      <xsl:value-of select="./message" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
   </strong>
  </label>
</div>
```

Now, that being said, what I need to do is something like the following:

```
<div class="radio">
  ...
      <xsl:if test="//form_data/withdraw_source = 'dpx_{./account_number}'">
          <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
  ...
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems  that `concat()` is what you are looking for.

Try:

```
 <xsl:if test="form_data/withdraw_source = concat('dpx_', ./account_number)">
```

Comment: When I use that, I get 2 errors, "concat requires 2 arguments", and "Attribute Value Template is not allowed here".

Comment: @webdevsoup: Sorry, copy/past error - get rid of `{`and  `}`

Comment: For some reason, that still is not working.  I do not get the Malformed XML data error anymore, and the page shows as it should.  However, the `<attribute>` for selected still isn't getting applied.

Comment: It appears as if it could be an issue with someone else.  I am trying to also append the value of `form_data/withdraw_source` on to another element via `<xsl:value-of select="" />`, and it is NOT printing it out.  Somehow seems as if it's not being set.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I needed to change `<xsl:if test="form_data/withdraw_source = 'dpx'">` to `<xsl:if test="//form_data/withdraw_source = 'dpx'">` due to being within a foreach loop.  Now let me try your concat option.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  +1